# Should a one-to-one relation, column, or something else be used?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, normalization

Though my problem is specifically in Ruby on Rails, I'm also asking generally: I have a users table and want to designate some users to be students and others to be teachers. What is the best way to design the schema in this case?

Edit:
Though I originally accepted vonconrad's answer--it fits the original criteria--I have to reopen and adjust the question based on feedback from nhnb.

What should be done if students and/or teachers require additional (unique) attributes?

Comment: How likely is it that those roles will need additional, distinct attributes in the near future?

Comment: @nhnb: Though I can stand to go without that for now, it is very likely that will be desired in the near future. Is there a better way in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This greatly depends on how many the different attributes between the teacher and student there'll be as well as how often new unique attributes will be added or removed.  If the case is that they will differ a lot, you have two choses:

1. Make two models, one for Student and one for Teacher and use ruby include to share any logic between the two models.  Any associations that associate with a user, you would use a polymorphic association (`has_many :user, :polymorphic => true`)
2. Put the attributes in another table. For example: you'll have the `users` table and a `user_attributes` table.  `users` would have `id, user_type, username, etc.` and `user_attributes` would have `id, user_id, attribute_name, value`.

If, however, your different attributes between the two users are few and pretty rock solid, you should just consider using [**Single Table Inheritance**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Very helpful, and a head-scratcher at that. I think, in this specific case, I'll go with Single Table Inheritance. Thanks. And if anyone runs into an issue with link_to and form_for, I found this blog post with a workaround: http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I'd simply go with a single boolean column called `teacher`. If true, the user is a teacher. If false, it's a student. No need to create another model.

If you want **more than two** roles (say, student, teacher, administrator, janitor(?)), you can add another model called UserGroup. You'll also have to create a column in the users table called `user_group_id`. In the new model, you have a single row for each of the roles. Then, you specify the following relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

This will allow you to assign each user to a specific group.

Comment: I would assume that you're always going to have more roles later, to save some pain when it happens, but still a good answer. +1

Comment: Thanks. I will undoubtedly be expanding to more than two roles, so that was very helpful. Also, I think the second class should be UserGroup, correct?